# Prove that $\mathbb{P}(X\in B)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)$ for all borel sets $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, linear-transformations

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X_1,\cdots,X_n:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ be independent and $N(0,1)$-distributed random variables. Suppose that $Y_1,\cdots,Y_n:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ are random variables satisfying the following conditions:

1. $Y_i\in\color{red}{\mathcal{S}}:=\{\Sigma_{i=1}^na_iX_i:a_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$ for all $i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$;
2. $\text{Var}(Y_i)=1$ for all $i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$;
3. $\text{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)=0$ for any $i,j\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ with $i\neq j$.

Define $X,Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by $X:=(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ and $Y:=(Y_1,\cdots,Y_n)$.

Prove that $\mathbb{P}(X\in B)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)$ for all borel sets $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

I know that $\mathbb{P}(X\in B)=\mathbb{P}(X\in Q(B))$ for any borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and orthogonal linear transformation $Q:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, so I tried to find a orthogonal linear transformation $Q:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Y=Q\circ X$.

I know that $\{X_1,\cdots ,X_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{S}$, so I tried to find a linear transformation $\tilde Q:\mathcal{S}\to \mathcal{S}$ whose matrix with respect to the basis $\{X_1,\cdots ,X_n\}$ yields a orthogonal linear transformation $Q:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $Y=Q\circ X$. However I failed to find it.

---

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: *Hint.* Item 1 tells that $Y=AX$ for some matrix $A$. Then evaluate the covariance matrix for $Y$, $$ \mathbf{E}[YY^{\top}], $$ in two ways (one using the assumptions on $Y$, and the other using the assumptions on $X$) to show that $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.